# the_author() str_replace error

Tags: theme-development, blog, single

I Am Using WordPress 6.1 In Which I Am Calling the_author() function to get author name in single blog page. The problem is that it works properly when we call it in blog page but when I Call it in single blog page, it throws following error:
[image]

Single Blog Page Code

```
<div class="left d-flex flex-row gap-3 align-items-center">
        <span class="fw-600"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="fw-600"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: hey @Muhammad . Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes Thank You For Helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the author's name outside the loop, you must use the following code snippet.

**First answer: Your definite answer**

The code below first takes the `ID of the author` of the post. Then it displays the `author name` using the ID

```
    global $post;
    $get_AuthorId = $post->post_author;
    $getUser_name = get_userdata($get_AuthorId);
    echo $post_author = $getUser_name->user_login;   //  This returns the name of the author of the article
```

**An example of your code will be this**

```
    <div class="left d-flex flex-row gap-3 align-items-center">
        <span class="fw-600"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="fw-600"><?php echo $post_author; ?></span>
    </div>
```

**The second answer: using while**

If you want to display the author's name in while, use the following code
See the code below:

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="left d-flex flex-row gap-3 align-items-center">
        <span class="fw-600"><?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="fw-600"><?php echo the_author(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php the_content();  
endwhile;
?>
```

Pay attention that you must use this code in the `single.php` page of your wp theme template.

See in the image below, when we use **while**, it displays the **author name**

[image]

If you have any problem, please leave a comment.